# How to use Immutable.js with Redux and TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, angular, redux, immutable.js

I am trying to change my state-object to an immutable Immutable.js object, but I'm having big troubles with the type definitions. I tried to find similar issues on the net but couldn't really find anything helpful.

I have the following state which I want to convert into an Immmutable object.

```
export interface PostState {
  ids: number[];
  entities: { [id: number]: Post};
  loading: boolean;
  error: string;
};

export interface Post {
  id: number;
  comments: {
    ids: number[];
    loading: boolean;
  }
};
```

Any suggestions? How should I define these interfaces to ensure immutability with Immutable.js?

Answer (score 0):

> which I want to convert into an Immmutable object.

## Basic

The two great JavaScript structures are : `Object` (used as a `Dictionary` also called `HashMap` also called `Map`) and `Array` (also called `List` etc).

## Samples

In your state you have one Map:

```
entities: { [id: number]: Post};
```

And A few Arrays e.g.

```
ids: number[];
```

## Conversion

For Map, Immutable has its own Structure : https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/Map

For List there is : https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/List

## Declaration

Exactly what you would expect e.g. for `List`:

`ids: number[];` -> `ids: List<number>`

Comment: I changed everything like you said ( `entities: { [id: number]: Post};` becomes `entities: Immutable.Map<number, Post>;` etc). But when I want to initialize an Object from this interface, without setting any value in entities, I get an error. If I change `entities` to `entities: Immutable.Map<any, any>;` the error dissapears and with it also the type definitions, so I'm again at the starting point....

Comment: I am having difficulties with immutable.js and Angular 2 and typescript as well. See my question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38448132/how-to-declare-empty-immutable-set-in-typescript.  May I request of people who answer to please check their answer in actual code and not just post the docs.